# Something is blocking and slowing Windows 7 down when I loose the network connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, performance, freeze, debug

I've experienced this multiple times on various Windows installations on various work related devices. Sometimes when my laptop looses it's connection to the Intranet, the whole systems seem to hang. Explorer browses folders terribly slow, new processes won't start for a while and start in a burst after a good amount of time.

For me this seems to be related to a network resource not available any longer to the device. Since Windows still has a lock on the file, it tries to access it, but fails resulting in a eventually timouted connection. Up until the time out happens, basically nothing else can be run on the system. Application windows black out, the task bar can't accessed and Windows is offering me to shut every application down. I activated 'Airplane Mode' on my ThinkPad T440s to reproduce the problem and wasn't able to turn it back on, since the device slowed down immediately.

After some hours the device can be used normally. Usually this happens after standby or hibernate mode. The system can be used normally even though the network connection isn't back at the time.

Is there any way to analyze this situation any further? Is there some sort of log which is telling me which unavailable network resource is held by Explorer and is possibly blocking the whole system? Is there any kind of system log on Windows that I can access for this purpose?

On Unix based machines I would have analyzed the output and content of `dmesg` or `/var/log/`.

Comment: Can you see any processes using excessive amounts of CPU on the Task Manager?

Comment: CPU usage is at a normal operating level, for me and the user users of the machine. Nowhere near 100%. Most of the time far below 50%.